# how to get strut <html:select> value in java script in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, struts

i want countryid value in java script

```
<html:select property="countryid" onchange="retrieveURL();">
                <html:option value="-1">SELECT</html:option>
                <html:options collection="countryList" property="countryid" labelProperty="countryname" />
        </html:select>
```

can any one help

Comment: What's the name of the `html:form` where the `html:select` is situated?

Comment: When you're doing JavaScript, forget about Struts and its tags. JavaScript only sees the generated HTML.

Comment: oky JB NiZET so can you tell me how to get value from HTML Collection

Answer (score 0):

Consider your form called `uploadForm`. In your Javascript, you will do

```
var select = document.uploadForm.countryid;
var value = select.options[select.selectIndex].value;
```

I hope this helps.